# English word conjugation rules

Tags: grammatical-number, conjugation

I am a programmer whose most recent project involves Natural Language Parsing and I need to be able to conjugate English Verbs and Nouns.

I already have a list of Verb Irregulars but I am struggling to find a set of "rules" if you will, for conjugating regular English verbs. I know there are a few, various rules such as: "if the word ends in 'X', then the plural form would end in 'Y'" with the most basic being add an s to the end.

I am looking for the rules for finding the: Base form, Past simple, Past participle, 3rd person singular, Present participle Gerund

Also, I would be looking to do the same for finding the plurals and possessive forms of any given noun, along with a list of regulars. I have had no source of results or luck in my searching in this area and any help with conjugating (for lack of a better word) nouns would be very helpful

Sorry for what appears to be the lack of searching, trust me I have looked.

Comment: I highly doubt that these set of "rules" exist.

Comment: sorry, I am more of a programmer than a linguist, So I am used to assuming there are rules for pretty much everything.

Comment: Regular verbs and nouns follow rules (the clue is in the word *regular*!) so it should be possible to parse a sentence for known irregular words first, and anything else must follow regular principles. Barrie's answer is a good summary.

Comment: 'Formalizing' a natural language is going to be a daunting task. Only a part of the set of words will follow some rules, with exceptions within that. You will need to have at least three groups: those that strictly follow a pattern, those that follow a known alternate form, and those that better be treated as unique, and hence handled on a case-to-case basis.

Comment: This is a verb broad question. There are a lot of different parts to it.

Comment: All the rules for regular verb conjugation depend on **pronunciation,** not spelling. Spelling is independently irregular. If you must restrict yourself to spelling, you'll have to treat most inflection as irregularity. Database time; fill it once and refer to it constantly.

Answer (score 3):

English regular verbs have four rule-based forms. *Walk*, for example, has *walk, walks, walking, walked*. There are no rules for forming irregular verbs and each has to be learnt separately.

The regular plural of nouns is formed by the addition of *-s* to the singular, but if the noun ends in *-s, -z, -x, -ch or –sh*, it adds *-es*. A few nouns have irregular plurals. *Man* becomes *men*, for example, and *child* becomes *children*.

There are some exceptions, but the possessive of singular nouns is formed by the addition of *-'s*. The possessive of plural nouns is formed by the addition of *-s'*.

Verbs conjugate, but nouns decline.

Comment: don't forget if the noun or verb ends in _-y_ the y sometimes turns into an i.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are no all-encompassing rules.

But I got these from a grammar book (by Raymond Murphy). Hope they help:

1.If the Noun or Verb ends in -s, -ss, -sh,-ch and –x, put "+es" at the end.

2.Nouns ending in:

> A.    consonant + y  >>>>> ies
>
> B.     vowel + y  >>>>> ys

3.Verbs ending in:

> A.    consonant + y >>>>> ies/ ied
>
> B.    consonant + y >>>>> ying
>
> C.    vowel + y >>>>> ys / yed / ying
>
> D.    exceptions: pay, lay, say

4.Verbs ending in:

> A. ie >>>>> ying
>
> B. e >>>>> ing/ ed (except irregular)
>
> C. exceptions: be, see, agree

5.Verbs ending in

> A. vowel + consonant >>>>> doubled consonant + ing / + ed
>
> B. exception: over-1- syllable Verbs
>
> 1. stress on final syllable >>>>> doubled consonant + ing/ +ed
> 2. no stress on final syllable >>>>> single consonant + ing/ +ed
>
> (except British double “l” and American single “l”)
>
> C. consonant + consonant >>>>> single consonant + ing/ + ed
>
> D. vowel + vowel + consonant >>>>> single consonant + ing/ + ed
>
> E. y / w >>>>> single y/ w +ing/ + ed

Comment: Good luck depending on spelling.

Comment: Hi John. Yeah :-D

Comment: Hmmm, but no double letters for verbs with base forms ending in h, w, x, y, though :)